# C# Entity Framework issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a bit of an issue with my program now that I transferred it over to the Entity Framework context.  I keep getting an index out of range argument which means that my program is not counting the number of classes or keeping track of the total credit hours I am trying putting into my list box.  The program itself is supposed to take items selected from the combobox put them in the list box and write back to the database when the button is clicked.  I will be adding my code (at least what I think is relevant) down below.  Thanks and have a great day.

**My Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            context = new CourseContext();
            context.Courses.Load();
            courseBindingSource.DataSource = context.Courses.Local.ToBindingList();
            courseComboBox.DataSource = courseBindingSource.DataSource;
            courseComboBox.DisplayMember = "CourseNumber";
            courseComboBox.ValueMember = "CourseNumber";

            display = true;
            registeredCourseList.View = View.List;


            selectedContext = new SelectedCourseContext();
            selectedContext.SelectedCourses.Load();
            selectedCourseBindingSource.DataSource = selectedContext.SelectedCourses.Local.ToBindingList();

            for (int i = 0; i < context.Courses.Local.Count; i++)
            {
                string courseNumber = selectedContext.SelectedCourses.Local[i].CourseNumber;
            }
                statusMessageText.Text = $"{courses.Count} Courses available\n" +
                "Select a course from comboBox above";
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error reading data: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

private void courseComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (display)
        {
            Course chosenCourse = context.Courses.Local[courseComboBox.SelectedIndex];
            registeredCourseList.Items.Add(chosenCourse.ToString());

            //If the course is not registered for
            if (!courses[courseComboBox.SelectedIndex].IsRegisteredFor)
            {
                //If the creditTotal + the course credits is not less than or equal too 9
                if (creditTotal + chosenCourse.Credits <= 9)
                {
                    //The course is registered for
                    statusMessageText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    courses[courseComboBox.SelectedIndex].IsRegisteredFor = true;
                    registeredCourseList.Items.Add(courseComboBox.SelectedText);

                    //The statusMessageLabel reads the course name and finishes the statement
                    statusMessageText.Text = $"{chosenCourse.CourseNumber} selected";

                    //The credits are added to the total
                    creditTotal += chosenCourse.Credits;
                    totalCreditValueLabel.Text = $"{creditTotal}";
                }
                else
                {
                    /*If you have 9 credit hours or choose a course with more
                     * than 9 the program will not allow it and displays a message
                     */
                    statusMessageText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    statusMessageText.Text = "Cannot register for more than 9 credits";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /*If you have already selected a course the statusMessageText will
                 * Tell the user they have already selected that course
                 */
                statusMessageText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                statusMessageText.Text = $"{chosenCourse.CourseTitle} already selected";
            }

            SelectedCourse c = new SelectedCourse();
            c.UserID = userNameTextBox.Text;
            c.CourseNumber = chosenCourse.CourseNumber;
            selectedContext.SelectedCourses.Local.Add(c);
        }
    }
```

My Program

[image: enter image]

Error:

[image: enter image]

Comment: can you add a break point and stepping through the code?

Comment: Yes, but it just keeps going through it and giving me the error message.

Answer (score -1):

You need <= in your for loop:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= context.Courses.Local.Count; i++)
```

Comment: That guarantees that the last iteration will be out of range.  Indexes go from 0 to Count - 1.

Comment: I added the (int i = 1; i <= context.Courses.Local.Count; i++) and am still getting that error message.

Comment: You're using two separate collections (SelectedCourses.Local and Courses.Local) so SelectedCourses.Local has less items in its collection than Courses.Local. I'm not sure what you're doing in the for loop?? String courseNumber is never being used.

Comment: It should get the courseNumber and display it in the list box along with telling how many courses are available in the statusMessagetext box.

Comment: ok I got the statusMessageText box to display the correct number of courses available, but am still getting that error message when I try to move my selected course over to the list box.  Just to clarify it moves it over but then I get the message.

Comment: I got it to work like I wanted thank you guys so much.